# Error "ELIFECYCLE 4058" al instalar un módulo usando npm

Tags: javascript, nodejs, serialport

## Error:

Cada vez que intento instalar algún módulo usando npm obtengo este registro de salida en la consola:

```
1:C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g serialport
2:"CALL "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node.exe" 
3:"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" is not recognized as an
4:internal or external command,
5:programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
6:npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible --
7:are you offline?
8:npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during
9:revalidation.
10:
11:> @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install
12:C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
13:> prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || node-gyp rebuild
14:
15:npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
16:npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
17:npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
18:npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34;
19:npm ERR! errno -4058
20:npm ERR! @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install: `prebuild-install --tag-prefix @serialport/bindings@ || 
21:node-gyp rebuild`
22:npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Python34; ENOENT
23:npm ERR!
24:npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script.
25:npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26:
27:npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
28:npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-25T14_44_28_892Z-debug.log
```

*(Tener en cuenta que la enumeración de cada línea en este caso no se corresponde con las líneas de la salida real de la consola. Esto es solo para poder señalar cosas mejor.)*

> **Resumido:**
>
> - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> - npm ERR! errno -4058
> - npm ERR! Failed at the @serialport/bindings@8.0.6 install script.

Este error salta específicamente cuando intento correr el comando `npm install -g <module>` o incluso solo `npm install <module>` para cuando lo quiero hacer localmente.

## También

La salida de la consola que se puede ver entre la línea **2** y la línea **4** es algo que me sale **siempre** que intento correr un comando npm, independientemente si es `npm install <module>` o cualquier otro comando npm.

**Ejemplo:**

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm -v
"CALL "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g" npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
6.13.6
```

Como se puede ver en este (y en el anterior) ejemplo: **a pesar de que me salta este error, el comando se ejecuta de todos modos.**

## Info Extra

- Nunca tuve este problema antes en esta computadora, y no puedo encontrar ningún otro post en internet que hable exactamente sobre esto.
- Este preciso error me sale al intentar instalar "serialport" o "nodemon", sin embargo, puedo instalar "express" sin problemas, estos dos tienen problemas al ejecutar `install script` y `post-install script` respectivamente.
- NPM cache log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DOd4uYVjn_ko3ZWZOM8ceavx8w_yYSWY/view?usp=sharing
- > **SO:**----------- Windows 10
  >   **Node.js:**-----  v13.7.0
  >   **NPM:** --------- v6.13.6